# github workflow android build fails

Tags: android, github, github-actions

Github Action is failing to make Android build. The error I am getting is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app-core'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > The file '/home/runner/work/my-project/my-project/local.properties' could not be found
```

Yaml config:

```
name: Android Build

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Set Up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.11

      - name: Build Project
        run: ./gradlew assemble

      - name: Run Tests
        run: ./gradlew test

      - name: Lint Checks
        run: ./gradlew detekt ktlintCheck lint
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You need to show your `build.gradle` file, when I use `local.properties` file the `build.gradle` has an exists check before trying to load properties from it.

Comment: Hey @Andrew. You mean you need to see `build.gradle` file? If yes, then which one? The one in the :app-core module?

Comment: Yes, you showing us the :app-core modules `build.gradle` will help people fix your problem because `local.properties` file is meant for stuff local to each specific machine and it not guaranteed to exist or have the right properties set on other machines. So where the local.properties file is referenced must have an existence check and setting of any properties to sensible defaults for instances where it does not exist.

Comment: I am not sure how content of `build.gradle` file would help to people. None of the `build.gradle` scripts point to `local.properties` or use it in any other way. `local.properties` usually has a property of `sdk.dir` and it is never checked in to git repository because it is environment variable. The problem is more around how github figures out path to sdk. Personally, `/home/runner/work/my-project/my-project/local.properties` looks very suspicious to me. Why `my-project` is twice set in the path? Is it normal path to properties file?

Answer (score 0):

It might be something wrong with your github repo structure or in your `build.gradle` files, it's impossible to tell with so little info to go on.

My only other thought is that you seem to be using old versions of various `actions`

It could be an interaction with the old checkout version used and being checked out in the wrong structure.

But looking at the docs for checkout it uses `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`

Which is defined [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) as

> GITHUB_WORKSPACE  The default working directory on the runner for steps, and the default location of your repository when using the checkout action. For example, /home/runner/work/my-repo-name/my-repo-name.

This looks like yours is using the right location for the checkout if your repo is called `my-project`

It might be worth updating your yaml config to use more recent action versions. (see https://github.com/actions for availability and latest versions)

For a similar Android Build I used the below 2 months ago successfully:-

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Gradle Wrapper Validation
        uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@v1

      - name: Setup Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches/
            ~/.gradle/wrapper/
          key: cache-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle') }}
          restore-keys: cache-gradle-

      - name: Build
        run: ./gradlew :fixedheadertablelayout:assembleDebug --no-daemon
```

But now there are some later version of some of the `actions`

You can also see that I target my lib and sample app separately for build and test.

May be your `./gradlew assemble` should be `./gradlew :app-core:assemble`